A matrix inequality $X - \frac{1}{u^\top Xu} Xuu^\top X \succeq Y - \frac{1}{u^\top Yu} Yuu^\top Y$

Problem. Let $n\ge 2$. Let $X, Y$ be $n\times n$ real symmetric positive definite (PD) matrices with $X \succeq Y$ (i.e. $X - Y$ is positive semi-definite (PSD)). Let $u\ne 0$ be a $n\times 1$ real vector. Prove or disprove that
$$X - \frac{1}{u^\top Xu} Xuu^\top X
\succeq Y - \frac{1}{u^\top Yu} Yuu^\top Y.$$

I came up with this problem when I dealt with a question in this site. I verified the case $n = 2$ by Maple - a computer algebra system (CAS). In detail, let $Y = [y_1, y_2; y_2, y_3]$, $Z = [z_1, z_2; z_2, z_3]$, and $X = Y + Z$, and $u = [u_1; u_2]$.
The constraints are $y_1>0, y_3 > 0, y_1y_3 > y_2^2$ and $z_1 \ge 0, z_3 \ge 0, z_1z_3 \ge z_2^2$. Let $H = X - \frac{1}{u^\top Xu} Xuu^\top X
- Y + \frac{1}{u^\top Yu} Yuu^\top Y$. By Maple, we can verify that $\det H = 0$ and $H_{11} \ge 0$ and $H_{22} \ge 0$. Thus, $H \succeq 0$.
For the case $n = 3, 4$, I did some numerical experiment which supports the claim.
Any counterexample, or idea?

Approach 1. Since $X\succeq Y\succ0$, we have
\begin{align}
&A:=\pmatrix{u^\top\\ I}X\pmatrix{u&I}
=\pmatrix{u^\top Xu&u^\top X\\ Xu&X}\\
\succeq\ &B:=\pmatrix{u^\top\\ I}Y\pmatrix{u&I}
=\pmatrix{u^\top Yu&u^\top Y\\ Yu&Y}\\
\succeq\ &0.
\end{align}
Therefore, for any positive $t$, we have $0\prec(A+tI)^{-1}\preceq (B+tI)^{-1}$. In turn, by comparing the trailing principal $n\times n$ submatrices of both matrix inverses (in terms of inverses of Schur complements), we obtain
$$
\left(X+tI-\frac{1}{u^\top Xu+t}Xuu^\top X\right)^{-1}
\preceq
\left(Y+tI-\frac{1}{u^\top Yu+t}Yuu^\top Y\right)^{-1}.
$$
Take inverses on both sides (with the Loewner ordering reversed) and let $t\to0$, the result follows.

Approach 2. Let $C=Y^{1/2}X^{-1/2}$ and $v=X^{1/2}u$. The inequality is equivalent to
$$
I-\frac{vv^\top}{\|v\|^2}
\succeq
C^\top \left(I-\frac{Cv(Cv)^\top}{\|Cv\|^2}\right)C.
$$
Note that both sides are PSD and $v$ is in their null spaces. Therefore, it suffices to compare the two sides on $\operatorname{span}\{v\}^\perp$. However, the LHS is the identity map on $\operatorname{span}\{v\}^\perp$. In turn, it suffices to show that the spectral radius of the RHS is bounded above by $1$, but this is obvious because
$$
\rho\left(C^\top \left(I-\frac{Cv(Cv)^\top}{\|Cv\|^2}\right)C\right)
\le\|C\|_2^2\le1.
$$

Thank your very much! Very nice solutions.

Your first approach reminds me the well-known formula $(A + uu^\top)^{-1} = A^{-1} - \frac{A^{-1}uu^\top A^{-1}}{1 + u^\top A^{-1}u}$ (this formula flashed in my mind when I dealt with this problem. However I can not proceed at that time). We have $(X^{-1} + uu^\top/t)^{-1}
= X - \frac{Xuu^\top X}{t + u^\top X u}$. For all $t> 0$, we have $(X^{-1} + uu^\top/t)^{-1} \succeq (Y^{-1} + uu^\top/t)^{-1}$ which results in $ X - \frac{Xuu^\top X}{t + u^\top X u} \ge  Y - \frac{Yuu^\top Y}{t + u^\top Y u}$.

@RiverLi Your idea of using Sherman-Morrison formula is great. It makes the proof even more compact.
